# Syntax error in “insert into statement”

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I am working on a PAT for school can you please help me with my code keep getting the same error.

This is my first one

```
DMrecord.qryMembers.Paramcheck := true;
DMrecord.qryMembers.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Members '
            +'([MemberName],[MemberSurname],[Age],[CellNumber],[EmailAddress])'
            +' VALUES '
            +'(:MemberName, :MemberSurname, :Age, :CellNumber,:EmailAddress)';
             DMrecord.qryMembers.Parameters.ParamByName('MemberName').Value := sname;
             DMrecord.qryMembers.Parameters.ParamByName('MemberSurname').Value := ssurname;
             DMrecord.qryMembers.Parameters.ParamByName('Age').Value := iage;
             DMrecord.qryMembers.Parameters.ParamByName('CellNumber').Value := icellphone;
             DMrecord.qryMembers.Parameters.ParamByName('EmailAddress').Value := semail;
             DMrecord.qryMembers.ExecSQL;
```

This is my second one

```
DMrecord.qryResults.Paramcheck := true;
DMrecord.qryResults.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Member Result '
            +'([ClubNumber],[Event],[AverageTime/Distance],[Numberofcompetition],[Agegroup])'
            +' VALUES '
            +'(:ClubNumber, :Event, :AverageTimeDistance, :Numberofcompetition, :Agegroup)';
            DMrecord.qryResults.Parameters.ParamByName('ClubNumber').Value := iclubnumber;
            DMrecord.qryResults.Parameters.ParamByName('Event').Value := sevent;
            DMrecord.qryResults.Parameters.ParamByName('AverageTimeDistance').Value := ravg;
            DMrecord.qryResults.Parameters.ParamByName('Numberofcompetition').Value := inumcomps;
            DMrecord.qryResults.Parameters.ParamByName('Agegroup').Value := sagegroup;
            DMrecord.qryResults.ExecSQL;
```

I hope this makes it easier 
and thanks for the help

Comment: Give space after and before `values`

Comment: Your edit has been rolled back (@kobik beat me to it by about a second). If you have a new problem, create a **new question** and ask about it there. You may **not** edit the question into a new one after you've received answers to the original one; it invalidates those answers and makes the posters appear foolish and can cause them to get downvotes.  **If you change this question again, I'm going to flag it for a moderator's attention because you're violating the rules of this site.**

Answer (score 4):

In your second query, you use

```
'INSERT INTO Member Result '
```

This will cause an error, as the table name contains a space and isn't being escaped.  You need to wrap it in brackets:

```
'INSERT INTO [Member Result] '
```

Comment: I don't think the spaces are mandatory. but the [Member Result] is correct. +1

Comment: @kobik You're right - just tested that, and it didn't throw an error.  I always assumed it was.  Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Would there be a reason why my code does not make the changes in the database itself?

Comment: @Heinie How do you mean?

Comment: @siyual like i want the code to change the database but when i run the program it does not change anything as if the changes where made but not posted if that makes sence

Comment: @Heinie Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the programming language you're using to execute the SQL, so I can't help you there.  But if you can get the `INSERT` statement to run, as long as you have write permissions to the table, it should work.

Comment: @siyual Thank you so much you helped a lot and i will take a look into that .